# Swing - parent update from child actions

Tags: java, swing

(disclaimer: I'm very new to swing and have only just started on it, so I probably suck)

So my child class has a `MouseListener` that detects whenever the user double clicks on the class; however, right now, the parent class doesn't know that the child has detected the click. As for now, I'm thinking about having a reference to the parent class in my child class and call one of the parent's method whenever double click is detected; however, I think this is not good OO design.

Child Class:

```
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getClickCount() == 2) {
            isFlagged = true; //flags that this class has been doubleclicked
            //I'm thinking of doing something like:
            //parentClass.flagged(passInThisClass);
        }
    }
```

Parent Class:

```
for(childClass c : childrenClass) {
    if(c.isFlagged()) { //do action}
}
```

The problem is when I run the parent class for the first time, none of the children are flagged, thus no action is performed. When the child is flagged, the parent class doesn't know that it should run this for-each loop again, thus nothing happens again. I can like said, I can have the for-each loop in a method and have the child call the method whenever double-click is detected, but I'm sure there must be a better way to do this.

What is the best approach in this case?

Comment: This sounds like the classes extend `JFrame` and `JPanel` when they *probably* shouldn't. But it is hard to say with such abstract descriptions. For example, what should happen on double click? Why should it happen? More generally: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: The parent class extends JFrame, and the child class extends Jpanel. On double click, the child change should "change" to another class that is also a child of the parent class. But I don't think the specifics matter too much, I'm just hoping to see what other people do to "pass" the children's actions to their parent classes.

Comment: *"But I don't think the specifics matter too much"* They do if you want my specific interest or attention in solving the problem. Where is the MCVE?

Comment: Okay, I'll try my best here. This is for a photo application. The photo application will display a picture in the middle of the screen. There are many different modes that the pictures can be displayed: Photoview (displays photo), browser and splitview, which displays a thumbnail, which is a class similar to photo but not as complicated. When in browser or splitview, when the user doubleclicks on a specific thumbnail, the application should switch over to the photoview with the specific photo loaded. see [link] (http://kedwards.com/classes/AY2017/cs4470_fall/hw3.html)

Comment: Thanks for helping btw :) The page is a bit long; the revelant topics I think are the pictures, "thumbnail" and "doubleclick" section

Comment: OK, from your description it seems you should not be extending `JFrame` or `JPanel` in most cases. Secondly, don't put the listeners in the 'child classes' - that logic should go in a central class that controls all the logic of swapping views etc. It is just that the listeners would be added to the various panels just after they are created (by the main 'logic' class). That's about all I can recommend short of seeing an MCVE.

Comment: okay thanks; I'll try it from the parent class down

Comment: M-C-V-E *"**it** recognize whenever it is being clicked/doubleclick"* You're following the same warped logic being used all along. **It** does not need to 'know' anything! Instead, the logic class should possess/have reference to the the listener that is applied to that component. Once the logic class registers an event on that component, the logic class takes whatever action the logic class should take. During all this, the component that is being clicked (or double clicked) should just be doing whatever it's told to do by the logic class, whether that is zoom in, zoom out, scroll ..

Comment: .. or be replaced by another component.

Comment: Yeah I got it working now. thanks! what I did was in my child component, I passed in a reference to the parent class so the child class has access to the parent class. I also called the parent class's method when the action is performed so then the parent class knows that the child has be updated. Thanks for helping! This is just me not understanding OO (not just a Swing problem).